# 500 errors when loading .axd files in Sitecore CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am running Sitecore 6.6.0-Update 4, MVC. When I attempt to load the Content Editor, all resources load normally except for the /WebResource.axd and /ScriptResource.axd files. This causes errors when attempting to load the Rich Text Editor, and presumably causes errors elsewhere, as well.

I have verified that routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); is present in Global.asax. Is there anywhere else I can look to troubleshoot this issue?

Here is a copy of one of the error messages, retrieved from Fiddler:

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Specified method is not supported. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported. 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below. 

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.] 
System.Web.Routing.StopRoutingHandler.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +36 
Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHandlerWrapper.GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext) +33 
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache(HttpContextBase context) +11507752 
System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80 
System.Web .HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +270 




-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MVC did you use? Sitecore 6.6 only supports MVC3, you will get errors with MVC4.

Also - are you using the Sitecore supplied Global.asax or the standard MVC one?  The Sitecore version should not have any routing info in there. Here is a copy of my global asax from a 6.6 MVC implementation:

```
<%@Application Language='C#' Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application" %>
<script runat="server">
  public void Application_Start() {
  }

  public void Application_End() {
  }

  public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs args) {
  }

  public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
  {
    string frameworkVersion = this.GetFrameworkVersion();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frameworkVersion) && frameworkVersion.StartsWith("v4.", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
      args.User = Sitecore.Context.User;
    }
  }

  string GetFrameworkVersion()
  {
    try
    {
      return System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetSystemVersion();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Cannot get framework version", ex, this);
      return string.Empty;
    }
  }

</script>
```

How did you setup MVC? If in doubt follow [John Wests blog](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/Sitecore-MVC-Playground-Part-1-Enable-MVC.aspx) on setting it up.

Comment: I'm using MVC 3. The "routes.registerRoute()" was, in fact, part of my Global.asax file. I'm not sure how long this line was in the file, but when I removed that line, the issue went away. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Sitecore 6.6 with MVC 4 and everything is working fine. I had same problem as yours, but I commented this line

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); // commented this line
```

in Global.asax and this helps.